# Does Hazelcast provide ordering guarantee when we implement a mapstore with writebehind logic?

Tags: hazelcast

I have configured a write behind cache using hazelcast mapstore. Want to know whether the async queue which write behind maintains has ordering guarantees.

If so whats the config that is used to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is an ordering guarantee, that matches the nature of Hazelcast running on multiple machines -- hence partial ordering.

Imagine you had entries with keys "*X*" and "*Y*".

If you update "*X*" twice, the second update is guaranteed to be the last update of "*X*" written to the database.

If you update "*X*" and "*Y*" in parallel, these updates might occur on different hosts, and write to the database in parallel -- no guarantee of which write of the two happens first.

If this isn't the semantics you want, can you clarify the need please ?

Note also there an optimisation for the two updates to "*X*" case. With write-coalescing enabled, Hazelcast will skip the first write to the database and only do the second if they occur in quick succession. So only the second write occurs. You still have the latest value written, just not the intermediate -- less writes to the database so improves speed, but not so useful if you have any sort of trigger processing needing to see all changes.